# On Theoretical Bounds for Time Complexity of Integer Factoring

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, factoring, computational-complexity

Is there a theoretical bound on how fast a classical integer factorization algorithm (i.e., non-quantum algorithm) can be?

$$\begin{smallmatrix}
{\text {Factorization method}} &  {\text {Time complexity}} & {\text {Approx. discovery}} \\
{\text {Trial division}} &  O(\sqrt n) & n.d.\\
{\text {Kraitchik}} &  O(\sqrt n) & 1920 \\
{\text {Pollard $p-1$}} & O(p) & 1974\\
{\text {Pollard Rho}} &  O(n^{1/4} ({\log n})^2) & 1975 \\
{\text {Morrison & Brillhart, CFRAC}} &  O(n^{(2 + o(1)) \log \log n / \log n}  ) &  1975 \\
{\text {Williams $p+1$}} & O(p) & 1982\\
{\text {Pomerance, Quadratic sieve}} & L_n\bigg[\frac 1 2, \sqrt[3] \frac {64} 9\bigg] & 1985 \\
{\text {Montgomery, Multipolynomial Quadratic sieve}} & ? & 1985 \\
{\text {Lenstra, Elliptic Curve method}} & L_p\bigg[\frac 1 2, \sqrt 2\bigg] & 1987 \\
{\text {Pollard, Number Field sieve}} & L_n\bigg[\frac 1 3, \sqrt[3] \frac {64} 9\bigg] & 1988 \\
{\text {Shor, Quantum factoring}} & O({(\log n)}^2 {(\log \log n)} ) & 1994
\end{smallmatrix}$$

> $p$ refers to the smaller factor of $n$.
>
> **L-notation:** L-notation is an asymptotic notation analogous to big-$O$ notation, denoted as $L_{n}[\alpha ,c]$ for a bound variable $n$ tending to $\infty$. It is defined as $$L_{n}[\alpha ,c]=e^{(c+o(1))(\ln n)^{\alpha }(\ln \ln n)^{1-\alpha }}$$ where $c$ is a positive
> constant, and $\alpha$ is a constant $ 0 \leq \alpha \leq 1$.
>
> See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-notation

Shor's quantum factoring obviously shows a fast algorithm using a quantum computer. So, that establishes a bound. But are there any theoretical obstructions preventing a faster classical algorithm than what is known currently? If yes, please provide references.

**References:**

Fabrice Boudot, Pierrick Gaudry, Aurore Guillevic, Nadia Heninger, Emmanuel Thomé, et al.. The State of the Art in Integer Factoring and Breaking Public-Key Cryptography. IEEE Security and Privacy Magazine, 2022, 20 (2), pp.80-86. ff10.1109/MSEC.2022.3141918ff. ffhal-03691141 (Accessed online. Feb 8, 2023): https://hal.science/hal-03691141

Comment: 1. I read the article about Shor's algorithm carefully, but it could not convince me that a quantum computer would actually factor a number efficiently this way. 2. Please clarify the $L_n$ notation. 3. I do not think that it can be currently proven that there is no classical algorithm with a complexity equal to the complexity given for the Shor algorithm. 4. I even doubt that an algorithm with complexity $O(log(n))$ can currently be ruled out.

Comment: @Peter: Wikipedia gives two complexity estimates for Shor's quantum factoring algorithm. The first one is $O\!\left((\log N)^{2}(\log \log N)(\log \log \log N)\right)$ using fast multiplication and a second one $O\!\left((\log N)^{2}(\log \log N)\right)$ using a fast multiplication algorithm for integers by Harvey and Van Der Hoven. I have listed the second one in the table in the question.

*Harvey, David; van Der Hoeven, Joris (2020)*. "Integer multiplication in time $O(n \log n)$". Annals of Mathematics. doi:10.4007/annals.2021.193.2.4.

Comment: Also, could someone provide the complexity for MPQS? I couldn't find a reference that mentioned it clearly.